# R: Concatenate strings with same values

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   a
a   a
x   b
y   b
b   b
```

How can I use are to get something like:

```
a   1,2,3,4
b   x,y
```

Consider that the identifier **a** and **b** are also listed in column 1 but should not be part of the concatenated string. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Henry, my new question is an extension of the question you are linking to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the initial description,

```
aggregate(V1~V2, df1, toString)
#  V2         V1
#1  a 1, 2, 3, 4
#2  b       x, y
```

#### Update

Suppose, if we need to remove the elements in first column ('V1') that are also present in the grouping column ('V2') before we `paste` the elements of `V1` together, a couple of options are listed below:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[!V1 %chin% V2, toString(V1), by=V2]
#    V2         V1
#1:  a 1, 2, 3, 4
#2:  b       x, y
```

Or

```
 library(dplyr)   
 df2 %>%
     filter(!V1 %in% V2) %>% 
     group_by(V2) %>%
     summarise(V1=toString(V1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "x", "y"),
 V2 = c("a", 
 "a", "a", "a", "b", "b")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "a", "x", "y", "b"), 
 V2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. I just edit my question slightly. Do you also know a solution for the more advanced problem? Thank you!

Comment: @Arun Thanks, I thought `%chin%` was new.

Comment: @Arun I guess I could remove the `filter` option and put that in the `summarise`.  I was thinking this would be a bit more clear for the OP.

Comment: Thank you very much akrun! that worked like a charme! very much helped me to finish my work!